# Should we expect the surface rocks of Venus to be oxide poor?

Tags: planetary-science, venus, chemistry, geology

My thinking is that in an atmosphere rich in hot sulfuric acid they couldn't stand a chance. Although I am unsure of what exactly would be going on chemically at the interface between the venerean litho and atmo spheres.

Comment: I need some time to process [this paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1982LPSC...13....3B), which may contain the answer to your question. If anyone else wants to use it to answer before I can, feel free to do so.

Comment: I think that is the paper I need.

Comment: If you find the answer, don't forget that you can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

As best as I can understand from these papers, it would seem that the precise levels are not known, but that noticeable weathering on Venus implies significant(?) levels of oxidation on the surface. The papers primarily address the oxidation of **Fe** (iron) mineral on the surface.

Most of the material in the papers is derived from modeling of the surface and atmospheric interactions from what little data we have, as well as spectroscopy and other observations of the character of the surface material.

**Sources:**

- [The crust of Venus: Theoretical models of chemical and mineral composition - Barsukov, V. L., Volkov, V. P., & Khodakovskii, I. L.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1982LPSC...13....3B)
- [Must the Venus Surface Material Contain Hematite? - Wood, J. A.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1996LPI....27.1451W)